# How should I return a value from function?

Tags: java, function

Three ways I see here:

1) make function return that value explicitly

2) add additional argument to the function's argument list and pass string holder as that parameter. After the function completes its execution, that string holder will contain the result of the function.

3) throw an exception from that function that will contain the result.

I for myself see first choice more preferable because it's simple, intuitive and straight.

On the other hand, when execution of the function goes in a wrong way there may be additional choices like throw an exception or use a variable passed through parameter to save errors if any happen.

Intuitively, I see that ideal choice is to have explicit return value and throws declaration. So return value is used for normal execution and caught exception will signal about abnormal situation. But I myself don't like exceptions too much if only it is not the completely unpredictable error, so I'd use explicit return value and additional parameter to hold some extra-situation logs or errors.

Please advise books or articles on the subject (it shouldn't necessary talk about Java, any other languages with similar mechanisms are also suitable).

Comment: Are you talking about returning a "value" object? And BTW "its" has no apostrophe in "completes its execution"

Comment: @Bohemian when I was talking about additional parameter, yes. Something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java methods have *return* values for a reason: to return their results. In the vast majority of cases #1 should be your *only* choice. Even if you want to return a wrapper object e.g. because you need to return multiple values, you should probably just `return` the thing...

Exceptions are just that: they are thrown in exceptional (i.e. abnormal) circumstances. Since traditionally throwing an exception also implies a performance impact, exceptions should not be thrown during normal operation.

Why are you trying to confuse yourself?

**EDIT:**

On the other hand, exceptions are quite suitable for rare/abnormal conditions:

- They have built-in support for the generation of debugging information. Getting a stack trace is half the battle in dealing with most bugs.
- All decent debuggers allow for thrown exceptions to be used as a break point, which can be invaluable.
- Exceptions allow for error conditions to be passed up the method call chain relatively transparently, allowing for the error handling code to be placed with as much granularity as desired.
- Exceptions are the standard way to deal with error conditions in Java. This should be enough for most programmers. Please respect the people that will have to work with your code and don't break such basic conventions by reinventing the wheel...

Comment: i don't like the whole conception of exceptions very much because they became non-exceptional, so if they are not exceptional, why should I cause my program to go in abnormal way which probably will cause performance loss and other ugly things, instead of save that exception text and return it through additional 'validationFault' StringBuilder parameter.

Comment: @gasan: 1. Exceptions allow for proper debugging information (e.g. a stack trace) to be generated. 2. Exceptions can be easily caught in a debugger. 3. Exceptions allow errors to be propagated upwards the call chain in a standard manner

Comment: yes, but exception cause additional resource spent, so it's better to if your program control-flows in a standard manner, not through exceptions, if it's possible.

Comment: @gasan: Exceptions consume more resources only when they are thrown. Under normal circumstances they should rarely be thrown - definitely not often enough to impact performance. In fact, checking for errors manually is generally more expensive. *If* you have a case where an exception becomes part of the normal program flow, you need to rewrite your code, in general by performing a few pre-flight checks before you do whatever it is that throws the exception.

Answer (score 5):

You absolutely want option #1. Exceptions are not unpredictable; if you use them correctly, they are in fact entirely predictable. You can throw different exception types based on the error (FileNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, SomeConditionSpecificToMyAppException, etc), and those exceptions can contain any error or diagnostic information you need to convey.

Here's a good section in the Java SE tutorial on exceptions:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: I was talking about exception that may rise in 3rd party library e.g. and that are marked as runtime exception so you can't predict them unless they raise.

Comment: Yes, but you can't change what 3rd party libraries might return or throw. You CAN, however, catch those unpredictable exceptions from 3rd party libraries, wrap them in your own exception, and throw/handle that accordingly.

Comment: But isn't it more natural to not use that 'Exception-handling' mechanism at all? I think throwing an exception is generally a bad thing and cause performance loss and maybe other problems. I mean, if I can wrap exception and return that message through additional 'ValidationFault' StringBuilder parameter, I really want to do that instead.

Comment: @gasan: no, it's not more natural at all. Java has exceptions, and everybody uses them to signal exceptional cases. Doing otherwise would just confuse the users of your API, would make it look amateurish, and less usable. An exception is much more than a message in a StringBuilder. It has a type, a message, any numer of additional types fields. It also doesn't force the creation of empty StringBuilders at each call, and doesn't need the caller to inspect the StringBuilder after each call. It also makes programs much more robust, because it forces the caller to handle them.

Comment: @JBNizet if there was already an exception thrown, I don't see any evil to throw it upper the stack. I'm saying that if you're the one who writes `throw new Exception()` you shouldn't do that and use additional parameter instead. Also, in c++ in winapi it's a common used practice to return function values through a structure passed as a parameter. And function return value itself is only `true` or `false` and used to signal if something went wrong. I'm just trying to understand, what technique to use.

Comment: @gasan: 1. WINAPI is not exactly a good example of good software design. 2. In most cases WINAPI is a *C* API, not a C++ one. `C` does not support exceptions natively.

Comment: You should never do `throw new Exception();`. You should do `throw new MySpecificException("this specific thing went wrong");`. You may of course program in Java like you would do in C, but then why use Java in the first place? There is no single Java API that does what you suggest. Do it if you want, but you've been warned: it's bad design, and you'll piss off all the users of your API.

Comment: @JBNizet where is it said, that returning value using value-holder parameter is exactly a bad design?

Answer (score 1):

I would use choice 1 almost every time.  There is nothing stopping you throwing a Exception as required.

Answer (score 1):

Please read Code Complete by Steve McConnell. It's all there.

Comment: *Please* don't recommend a whole book as the answer to a single question. You should *at least* quote a few relevant parts...

Comment: This answer is as general as the question is. In the book these topics take about 4-5 chapters. To find out a short answer we should first ask the author to make the question more specific. Anyway, he actually _asked_ to advise books or articles.